# How to remove tooltips in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm looking for a way to disable the mouseover tooltips for images and hyperlinks in Internet Explorer.
I've dug through the settings of IE 8 with no luck.  My research suggests that only [Opera](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1014052) has ever had this option.

I checked [my copy of IE3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114417/stack-exchange-sites-look-terrible-in-internet-explorer) and it doesn't have tooltips for links, though it does for images.  It too has no setting to get rid of the tooltips, so it seems like this has never been an option in IE.

[image]

I understand that this is a feature of HTML and that it's up to the web page designer to determine if the page has these tooltips.  I just want to get rid of all of them that I come across.  There are good reasons to disable these.  For example, [this is an issue for some people with epileptic seizures](http://forum.sysinternals.com/feature-req-option-to-disable-tooltips_topic16952.html).

How can I remove tooltips for all pages while using Internet Explorer?

Comment: I would assume this is best solved by a Greasemonkey equivalent, like [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/).

Answer (score 3):

As remarked by @Oliver Salzburg, the only solution is to modify the html document in order to
get rid of these pesky tooltips, because IE does insist on them when they are there. Your tool would be [Trixie](http://www.bhelpuri.net/Trixie/), which is to IE what Greasemonkey is to Firefox.

You could base your script on the one found in [Hack 70. Make Image alt Text Visible](http://gaezipserver.appspot.com/tools/greasemonkey-hacks-tips-tools-for-remixing-the-web-with-firefox-hacks/greasemonkeyhks-CHP-8-SECT-5.html).

I am not a user of Greasemonkey/Trixie, but I would imagine that you could start with something like this totally untested script for img tags :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Alt Tooltips
// @namespace   http://www.superuser.com/
// @description Erase Alt text from images
// @include     *
// ==/UserScript==


var res = document.evaluate("//img", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
var i, el;
for (i=0; el=res.snapshotItem(i); i++) {
  el.alt='';
}
```

With a similar script for hyperlinks.

Comment: looks like you would strip alt info and titles:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/toolmsg.shtml

Comment: @conspiritech: Correct. This can be done by adding into the loop `el.title='';`.

Comment: Seems like Trixie is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these options are configurable in the registry (this is in my notes file for explorer, not on a windows box currently, but it should give you an idea where to look for IE)

for explorer, they are:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

"EnableBalloonTips"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

"FolderContentsInfoTip"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\tips]

"Show"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

"StartButtonBalloonTip"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

"ShowInfoTip"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]

"NoSMBalloonTip"=dword:00000000

- Another alternative would be to use a user css (speculation)

Comment: These registry settings are for Windows Explorer, not Internet Explorer. Regarding CSS, it can modify the look but not the contents of the html document.

Comment: I stated such at the top of my post since the keys are similar and I don't have a windows clunker around to take the 5 minutes to poke around in regedit looking for something similar, I thought it may be helpful to someone else who could (not enough points to just comment when I posted it either - 1st day here).  With css you could set the delay time to 9999 with a .tooltip {transition: display 0s linear 9999s;} , but I am a bit rusty on my css

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. You can't style the `alt` attribute directly in css, as it only inherits from the img element or its parent(s). However, `title` can be styled with a CSS rule like "img [title]", but whether this includes transforms (for all browsers) needs to be checked (and in any case doesn't fully answer the post).